AWS SNS's CFT Deployment Failed due to error : Subscription already exists with different attributes
I am trying to add a filter to an already existing subscription to an SNS topic. When I deploy the stack using Cloud formation template, it gives me error -

"Invalid parameter: Attributes Reason: Subscription already exists with different attributes"

I was able to deploy it by deleting and then recreating the subscription with the filter, but this does not seems the optimal approach, especially for prod environments.
Any suggestions how I can overcome this error?
The earlier I was using below code to deploy without subscription -
 abcSNSSubscription:
    Type: 'AWS::SNS::Subscription'
    DependsOn: abcSNSTopic
    Properties:
      Endpoint: !Ref SNSEmailSubscriptionEndpoint
      Protocol: email
      TopicArn: !Join
        - '-'
        - - !Sub "arn:aws:sns:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}"
          - abc-loader-alert
          - !Ref Environment
          - !Ref Region

Below is the code that I am using now -
  abcSNSSubscription:
    Type: 'AWS::SNS::Subscription'
    DependsOn: abcSNSTopic
    Properties:
      Endpoint: !Ref SNSEmailSubscriptionEndpoint
      Protocol: email
      TopicArn: !Join
        - '-'
        - - !Sub "arn:aws:sns:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}"
          - abc-loader-alert
          - !Ref Environment
          - !Ref Region
      FilterPolicy:
        AlertType:
          - anything-but:
            - Success
      FilterPolicyScope: MessageAttributes

Thanks

I am answering my own post for anyone that may face this issue in the future.
I contacted AWS support for this issue, and they said this is the expected behaviour for changing any subscription attributes for an SNS topic, if updated using CloudFormation template.
For example, if you have deployed a subscription for an SNS topic without a filter policy. But at a later stage, you want to add a filter policy for the subscription, you wont be able to do that using CloudFormation, as AWS does not replace the subscription with new attributes. It will error out saying 'Subscription already exists with different attributes', and will not let you update it directly.
If you want to update the subscription without removing it entirely and then redeploying, you will need to use the SNS API to update the subscription with new attribute.
I am not sure why AWS has such behaviour for SNS subscriptions.
